# can't execute the blender python through subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess

My blender is at the path of `'/home/abc/Destkop/blender/blender-2.78'`. When command line is at the path `'/home/abc/Destkop/blender/blender-2.78'`, executing `'./blender -b /home/abc/Destkop/blender/car.model'` through command line is working.

I am trying to execute blender in python through subprocess, but the code doesn't work with an error `"/usr/bin/python: can't open file ./blender -b /home/abc/Destkop/blender/car.model"`, but the path is all right

here is my code

```
import os
import sys
import subprocess

if __name__="__main__":
    os.chdir("/home/abc/Destkop/blender/blender-2.78")
    subprocess.Popen([sys.executable],"./blender -b /home/abc/Destkop/blender/car.m
```

Comment: Is your system the same version as the blender Python interpreter?  ( https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/troubleshooting/python.html )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
subprocess.check_call(["./blender", "-b", "/home/abc/Destkop/blender/car.m"])
```

Note that the `shell` arg defaults to `False`, which means the `args` must be a *sequence* (list or tuple) of words making up the command-line, not a single command-line string.